# How to make the colorbar of a geopandas plot independent of vmax?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I use the following code to make nice world map with some statistics:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mplc
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
world = world[world.name != "Antarctica"]

np.random.seed(123)
countries = world['name'].sample(75, replace=True).tolist()

data = pd.DataFrame({'country': countries, 'count': np.random.randint(0, 500, 75)})

merged_data = world.merge(data, left_on='name', right_on="country", how="left")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

cmap = mplc.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("custom", ["r", "b"])

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="4%", pad=0, aspect=10)

merged_data.plot(column='count', ax=ax, cax=cax, cmap=cmap, linewidth=0.5, legend=True, edgecolors="k", missing_kwds={'color': 'lightgrey'}, legend_kwds={'label': "Number of people", 'orientation': "horizontal"}, vmin=0, vmax=3000)

fig = ax.figure
cb_ax = fig.axes[1]
cb_ax.tick_params(labelsize=8.5, size=2.5, direction="in")

ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

Everything looks good (Figure 1) untill I change `vmax=3000` with other data, and then suddenly the colorbar becomes long and narrow (Figure 2).

Is there a way to make the colorbar independent of `vmax` so that it does not change when I make other plots with other values? I want it to look as similar as possible in my report.

[image]
Figure 1: Good looking colobar -- what I want for all the figures.

[image]
Figure 2: Long and narrow colorbar -- not what I want.

---

Edit: Included a `MWE` as suggested by @JohanC.

Comment: The problem is probably caused by `aspect=10` in `divider.append_axes(...)`, I have no experience with that parameter in a colorbar, but it is probably the ratio between the x-axis in data units, and the y-axis (which have some unknown internal data units). Could you try to leave out that parameter (or try `aspect=10*3000/50`)? And maybe experiment a bit with the `size=` parameter?

Comment: The problem appears to depend on both `size` and `aspect`. I tried experimentng with them but I am never able to replicate the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I managed to solve it by calculating the `cb_width` and `cb_height` and then pass it to `aspect_ratio` before defining the `cax.set_aspect(aspect_ratio)`:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mplc
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import geopandas as gpd

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
world = world[world.name != "Antarctica"]

np.random.seed(123)
countries = world['name'].sample(75, replace=True).tolist()

data = pd.DataFrame({'country': countries, 'count': np.random.randint(0, 500, 75)})

merged_data = world.merge(data, left_on='name', right_on="country", how="left")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))

cmap = mplc.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("custom", ["r", "b"])

divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
cax = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="5%", pad=0, aspect=40)

vmin = 0
vmax = 3000

merged_data.plot(column='count', ax=ax, cax=cax, cmap=cmap, linewidth=0.5, legend=True, edgecolors="k", missing_kwds={'color': 'lightgrey'}, legend_kwds={'label': "Number of people", 'orientation': "horizontal"}, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

fig = ax.figure
cb_ax = fig.axes[1]

cb_width = cb_ax.get_window_extent().width / fig.dpi
cb_height = cb_ax.get_window_extent().height / fig.dpi

aspect_ratio = cb_width / cb_height

cax.set_aspect(aspect_ratio)

cb_ax.tick_params(labelsize=8.5, size=2.5, direction="in")

ax.set_axis_off()
plt.show()
```

I am not sure how robust this solution is, so please do not hesitate to comment or make different answers.